# ISPconfig, domain name text box cleared when I press tab key

Tags: apache2, cpanel

In ISPconfig I have noticed one problem from yesterday.

It is clearing the domain name text box when I press tab key after I type domain name. I am trying to add new domain but the domain name is getting cleared on blur. So when I click on submit, it throws an error "Domain name is Empty"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Problem was when I enable domain limit for client, it creates drop-down menu for domain (this might be ispconfig bug). I removed the limit and again started working.